# Get first record from duplicate records and use its identity in other tables

Tags: sql-server, unique

I have two temp tables in which there are duplicates. Two tables contains records as below.

```
DECLARE @TempCompany TABLE (TempCompanyCode VARCHAR(100), TempCompanyName VARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO @TempCompany VALUES ('00516','Company1')
INSERT INTO @TempCompany VALUES ('00135','Company1')
INSERT INTO @TempCompany VALUES ('00324','Company2')
INSERT INTO @TempCompany VALUES ('00566','Company2')
SELECT * FROM @TempCompany 

DECLARE @TempProduct TABLE (TempProductCode VARCHAR(100), TempProductName VARCHAR(100), TempCompanyCode VARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO @TempProduct VALUES ('001000279','Product1','00516')
INSERT INTO @TempProduct VALUES ('001000279','Product1','00135')
INSERT INTO @TempProduct VALUES ('001000300','Product2','00135')
INSERT INTO @TempProduct VALUES ('001000278','Product3','00566')
INSERT INTO @TempProduct VALUES ('001000278','Product3','00324')
INSERT INTO @TempProduct VALUES ('001000304','Product4','00566')
SELECT * FROM @TempProduct
```

Company is master table and product is child table. Product contains reference of company. Now these are my temp tables and I need to insert proper values from these tables to my main table.

I want to insert records as following

```
DECLARE @Company TABLE(CompanyID INT IDENTITY(1,1), CompanyCode VARCHAR(100), CompanyName VARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO @Company VALUES ('00516','Company1')
DECLARE @IDOf00516 INT = @@IDENTITY
INSERT INTO @Company VALUES ('00324','Company2')
DECLARE @IDOf00324 INT = @@IDENTITY
SELECT * FROM @Company 

DECLARE @Product TABLE(ProductID INT IDENTITY(1,1), ProductCode VARCHAR(100), ProductName VARCHAR(100), CompanyID INT)
INSERT INTO @Product VALUES ('001000279','Product1',@IDOf00516)
INSERT INTO @Product VALUES ('001000300','Product2',@IDOf00516)
INSERT INTO @Product VALUES ('001000278','Product3',@IDOf00324)
INSERT INTO @Product VALUES ('001000300','Product4',@IDOf00324)
SELECT * FROM @Product
```

I have attached the following image for how it looks when running the queries.

[image: How it should be inserted]

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably first insert unique records from tempCompany to Company table, then do an insert from TempProduct with a lookup to the inserted Company tables.

I.e. first insert companies:

```
INSERT INTO @Company (CompanyCode, CompanyName)
SELECT temp.TempCompanyCode, temp.TempCompanyName 
FROM @TempCompany AS temp
```

Then insert products using a join to find the companyid:

```
INSERT INTO @Product (ProductCode, ProductName, CompanyId)
SELECT temp.TempProductCode, temp.TempProductName, c.CompanyID
FROM @TempProduct AS temp
    JOIN @Company AS c ON temp.TempCompanyCode = c.CompanyCode -- Lookup to find CompanyID
```

However this does not take into account duplicates and the possibility that the main tables already have the records inserted.
Adding duplicate and check for already existing records the end result could look like:

```
--1. insert records not already in company table:
INSERT INTO @Company (CompanyCode, CompanyName)
SELECT DISTINCT temp.TempCompanyCode, temp.TempCompanyName 
FROM @TempCompany AS temp
    LEFT JOIN @Company AS c ON temp.TempCompanyCode = c.CompanyCode -- Will match Companies that already exists in @Companies
WHERE c.CompanyID IS NULL -- Company does not already exist
ORDER BY temp.TempCompanyCode 

--2. insert product records:
INSERT INTO @Product (ProductCode, ProductName, CompanyId)
SELECT DISTINCT temp.TempProductCode, temp.TempProductName, c.CompanyID
FROM @TempProduct AS temp
    JOIN @Company AS c ON temp.TempCompanyCode = c.CompanyCode -- Lookup to find CompanyID
    LEFT JOIN @Product AS p ON temp.TempProductCode = p.ProductCode AND temp.TempCompanyCode = c.CompanyCode -- Will match products that already exists in @Products
WHERE p.ProductID IS NULL -- Product does not already exists
ORDER BY c.CompanyID, temp.TempProductCode

--3. Check result
SELECT * FROM @Company
SELECT * FROM @Product
```

Note that i make use of LEFT JOIN and add a WHERE condition to check whether the record already exists in your main tables.
This could very well be achieved using the [MERGE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) statement - but I'm accustomed to the slighty less readable LEFT JOIN/WHERE method :)

EDIT

Only TempCompanyName is to be used for determining whether a row in TempCompany is unique. I.e. Company1 with CopmpanyCode 00135 should *not* be inserted.

To achieve this, I would make use of [ROW_NUMBER](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) in helping finding the company rows to insert. I've added an identity column to @TempCompany to make sure the first row inserted will be the row used (i.e. to make sure 00516 is used for Company1 and not 00135).

New @TempCompany definition:

```
DECLARE @TempCompany TABLE (TempCompanyId INT IDENTITY(1,1), TempCompanyCode VARCHAR(100), TempCompanyName VARCHAR(100))
```

And updated script with row_number added and an extra join from Product via TempCompany (on name) to Company. The extra join is to enable both Product1 with CompanyCode 00516 and CompanyCode 00135 to be handled correctly:

```
--1. insert records not already in company table:
;WITH OrderedTempCompanyRows AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY TempCompanyName ORDER BY TempCompanyId) AS RowNo, TempCompanyCode, TempCompanyName FROM @TempCompany)
INSERT INTO @Company (CompanyCode, CompanyName)
SELECT DISTINCT temp.TempCompanyCode, temp.TempCompanyName 
FROM OrderedTempCompanyRows temp
    LEFT JOIN @Company AS c ON temp.TempCompanyName = c.CompanyName -- Will match Companies that already exists in @Companies
WHERE temp.RowNo = 1 -- Only first company according to row_number
    AND c.CompanyID IS NULL -- Company does not already exist
ORDER BY temp.TempCompanyName 

--2. insert product records:
INSERT INTO @Product (ProductCode, ProductName, CompanyId)
SELECT DISTINCT temp.TempProductCode, temp.TempProductName, c.CompanyID
FROM @TempProduct AS temp
    JOIN @TempCompany tc ON temp.TempCompanyCode = tc.TempCompanyCode -- Find Companyname in @Tempcompany table
    JOIN @Company AS c ON tc.TempCompanyName = c.CompanyName -- Join to @Company on Companyname to find CompanyID
    LEFT JOIN @Product AS p ON temp.TempProductCode = p.ProductCode AND temp.TempCompanyCode = c.CompanyCode -- Will match products that already exists in @Products
WHERE p.ProductID IS NULL -- Product does not already exists
ORDER BY c.CompanyID, temp.TempProductName

--3. Check result
SELECT * FROM @Company
SELECT * FROM @Product
```

Comment: Sorry, By mistake I forgot to add some of the records to my question. I have updated my question. **DISTINCT** will not work for me because though the first 2 records from **TempCompany** table are distinct, I only want to save first record to the **Company** table and use its IDENTITY in **Product** table.

Comment: So you basically want to use CompanyName as the key for distinct? In your example data in effect disregarding the CompanyCode 135. But still match the products to be inserted with CompanyCode 135? I would have liked to store both companycodes in the company table. Why would you not want to store both rows?

Comment: I updated the answer adding an edit section at the end which should satisfy your specifications. Not entirely sure I like this solution though, but I guess it all depends on your specification / why you do not want to store all combinations of companyname and companycode.